# Localising values within xml tags

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization

This is an overview of the overall code flow.

FormatCode.xml is one of the input files with this kind of format.

```
<FormatCode id="405">

<Map>
<enumvalue>0</enumvalue> 
<actualvalue>Off</actualvalue>
</Map>

<Map>
<enumvalue>1</enumvalue> 
<actualvalue>Band1</actualvalue>
</Map>

<Map>
<enumvalue>2</enumvalue> 
<actualvalue>Band2</actualvalue>
</Map>

<Map>
<enumvalue>3</enumvalue> 
<actualvalue>Band3</actualvalue>
</Map>
 </FormatCode>
```

My application reads the values from this xml file into the following CLR object in the model. Other xml files are also used as input for some of the fields in the class but let's not bother.

```
public class parameter
{
    public string ParameterName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Enumvalue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string CurrentValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Eveentually this goes into the xaml through the viewmodel.

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="FnNameLbl" Text="{Binding Path=ParameterName}" >
 <ComboBox ItemSource="{binding protset}" displaymemeberpath="{binding path=current Value}">
```

protset is ObservableCollection.

Now the UI labels like submit,apply have been localised through resx files already.

My question is what is an optimal way to localise the values in formatcode.xml into english,german,chinese and so on.

Band1
Band2

The samples i see mostly deal with localising ui related labels and content. Though we are dealing with ui partly in this case, its the values coming from the business process that has to be localised.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a binding converter? Here is what I use, along with a Translate string extender that performs the actual translation.

```
public class LocalizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return ((string)value).Translate(culture);
        }
        return null;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return (string)value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've included code below for using xml files for localization. You can even update the xml interactively. Chooser is simply a dialog we use to present a list of choices to the user. The implementation of that is trivial, and not included. TextEntry is similar, a dialog which accepts input from the user.

In my base window class, I add a TextInput listener to trap CTRL+T (update translation xml) or CTRL+I (interactive).

```
window.TextInput += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.ControlText == "\x14") // Ctrl+T
    {
        "".Translate(true);
    }
    if (args.ControlText == "\x09") // Ctrl+I
    {
        "".Translate(true, true);
    }
};

public static class LocalExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string,SortedDictionary<string,string>> languages = new Dictionary<string,SortedDictionary<string,string>>(5);
    private static bool autoAdd;
    public static bool interactiveAdd;

    public static string Translate(this String phrase, bool autoAdd, bool interactive = false)
    {
        var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures);
        var chooser = new Chooser(Application.Current.Windows[0], "Translate from English To:", cultures.Select(culture => culture.EnglishName));
        chooser.ShowDialog();
        var selectedCulture = cultures.First(candidate => candidate.EnglishName == chooser.selectedItem);

        Localize.SetDefaultCulture(selectedCulture);

        LocalExtensions.autoAdd = autoAdd;
        LocalExtensions.interactiveAdd = interactive;

        return phrase.Translate();
    }
    public static string Translate(this String phrase)
    {
        return phrase.Translate(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    public static string Translate(this String phrase, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phrase)) return phrase;


        var lang = culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        SortedDictionary<string,string> translations;
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"Languages"))
        {
            return phrase;
        }
        var pathName = FindFile("Languages\\" + lang + ".xml");

        if ( !languages.ContainsKey(lang) ) {
            try {
                var xaml = File.ReadAllText(pathName, Encoding.UTF8);
                translations = (SortedDictionary<string, string>)XamlServices.Parse(xaml);
            } catch(Exception) {
                translations = new SortedDictionary<string,string>();
            }
            languages.Add(lang,translations);
        } else {
            translations = languages[lang];
        }

        if (translations.ContainsKey(phrase))
        {
            // return the translation for the specified phrase
            var tran = translations[phrase];
            var result = InteractiveUpdate(phrase, tran);
            if ( result != tran ) {
                translations[phrase] = result;
                SaveChanges(translations,pathName);
            }
            return translations[phrase];
        }

        // HACK: This is enabled by pressing CTRL+T on any window in the App.
        // Please note that any phrases in that window will not be translated
        // only phrases loaded in subsequent windows.
        if (LocalExtensions.autoAdd)
        {
            var result = InteractiveUpdate(phrase,phrase);
            translations.Add(phrase, result);
            SaveChanges(translations, pathName);
        }
        return phrase;
    }
    private static void SaveChanges(SortedDictionary<string,string> translations, string pathName)
    {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(pathName, false, Encoding.UTF8);
            XamlServices.Save(writer, translations);
            writer.Close();
    }
    private static string InteractiveUpdate(String phrase, String tran)
    {
        // HACK: Interactive update will be enabled by pressing CTRL+I on any window.
        // The same caveat applies here as with autoAdd above.
        if (interactiveAdd && !phrase.StartsWith("pack:"))
        {
            interactiveAdd = autoAdd = false;

            var tb = new TextBox
            {
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                AcceptsReturn = true,
                Height = double.NaN,
                Width = double.NaN,
                Text = tran
            };
            var te = new TextEntry(Application.Current.Windows[0],"Please translate:",tb,TextEntryType.AlphaNumeric);
            te.blurEnabled = false;
            te.ShowDialog();
            tran = tb.Text;

            interactiveAdd = autoAdd = true;
        }
        return tran;
    }

    private static string FindFile(string fileName)
    {
        var candidatePath = fileName;
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            candidatePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + fileName;
            if (!File.Exists(candidatePath) && ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                candidatePath = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + "\\" + fileName;
            }
        }
        return candidatePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort mate. will take sometime for me to absord it all.